# How to add navigation buttons to WebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview

I have a function, that open PDF file in WebView in fullscreen mode.

How to add "Done" button, that can close WebView?

```
- (IBAction)openPDF:(id)sender {
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];


    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    webView.frame = frame;

    [webView loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Comment: add button on webview and give action to that button.

Comment: Alternatively, try [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController) for an out-of-the-box implementation of web view with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Make UIWebView *webView global,

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;
```

then init that webview inside **- (IBAction)openPDF:(id)sender** method;

```
_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

Add a DONE button to your view, and in `- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender` method

remove the webview from the view;

```
[_webview removeFromSuperview];
_webView = nil;
```

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is, create a new sub class of **UIViewController**, say WebViewController with a nib. Then I would add an **UINavigationBar** with a **close button** and an **UIWebView**. 
Now do something like:

```
WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
webViewController.loadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
[self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
[webViewController release]; //If you use ARC, the no need for this line
```

In your **WebViewController** define:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *loadURL;

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender;
```

Implement :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.loadURL];
   [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
 }


- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```